# Docker Desktop problem with Docket.DotNet, Calling _dockerClient.Containers.StartContainerAsync() 2nd time will fail with OperationCanceledException

Tags: .net, docker, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

I tried to use docker to run integrated testing with AWS Cloud by using [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/microsoft/Docker.DotNet) version 2.1.0.3(38240).

However whenever StartContainerAsync() is called the second time, it will fail with an OperationCanceledException.

Here is the step to reproduce the issue:

I tried both localstack/localstack and dynamodb-local images, yet which images to use have nothing to do with the error I believe.

1. Pull images from Docker CLI 
   Run a Console App, which makes the following calls
2. Call _dockerClient.Containers.CreateContainerAsync()
3. Call _dockerClient.Containers.StartContainerAsync()
4. Call _dockerClient.Containers.StopContainerAsync()
5. Call _dockerClient.Containers.RemoveContainerAsync()
6. Call _dockerClient.Containers.CreateContainerAsync()
7. Call _dockerClient.Containers.StartContainerAsync() // program will
   fail here.

Or

1. Pull images from Docker CLI 
   Run Console App the first time, which makes the following call
2. Call _dockerClient.Containers.CreateContainerAsync()
3. Call _dockerClient.Containers.StartContainerAsync() // program will fail here.

StartContainerAsync() will fail as long as it is running the second time. It does not have to be in the same process. Then docker desktop will into a non-responsive state, to fix it, I have to reset docker to factory defaults, if simply try to restart docker will get a “Timed out waiting for the lifecycle-server to start” error.

This behavior is duplicated in two different physical machines.

Any help is appreciated thank you in advance.

I am using Windows 10 Pro, Visual Studio 16.3.1 and Docker Desktop version 2.1.0.3(38240)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was caused by my VPN software Astrill, once I uninstall its LSP. The program works fine now.

I have the same software installed on both of my Desktop and Laptop. That is why this behavior is duplicated in both machines.